# How to process data after a request

Tags: python, django

I have a form where you can input some data, but i want to return the view with a suc6 message and process that data and finally add it to the database.

I have everything working but if I process the data it doesn't return the view right away and I don't know if its good practice to use a Thread instead of Processing the data in the view.py

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case. But I would suggest processing the data in view.py because you want to respond with a success message after the processed data is safely stored in database. With thread you might have a problem if your thread breaks after you responded with a success message.

Comment: example: You have to post a URL, the view checks if the URL exists and adds it to the database, but I don't want a success message just get redirected instantly, do i have to use Threads here or is there a better way. And will you run into issues if you run 10 thread that access the database at the same time?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest Threads, there could be all sorts of problems with them. However if you want to do async processing, you can use a message queue. The most commonly used with django is [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) so have a look if it suits your needs.